# convert hashed array to string

Tags: ruby

```
hash = { "d" => [11, 22], "f" => [33, 44, 55] }
```

is there an one liner to get a string like below:

```
d:11,d:22,f:33,f:44,f:55
```

thanks!

Great, thanks for the tip.  Why this code doesn't work, only difference is I replaced `vs.map` with `vs.each`:

```
hash.map {|k,vs| vs.each {|v| "#{k}:#{v}"}}.join(",")
```

which returns `"11,22,33,44,55"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two nested calls to `map` to get an array of arrays of "key:value" strings, and then use `join` to turn it into one comma-separated string:

```
hash.map {|k,vs| vs.map {|v| "#{k}:#{v}"}}.join(",")
```

Comment: why this code doesn't work, only difference is i replaced "vs.map" with "vs.each", hash.map {|k,vs| vs.each {|v| "#{k}:#{v}"}}.join(","), which returns "11,22,33,44,55"

Comment: @user: Because `each` executes the block on each element, but throws the results away and then returns the receiver unchanged. You use `each` for the side-effects of the block only and in this case there are none. So in other words your code does the same as just `hash.map {|k,vs| vs}.join(",")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash.keys.map {|k| hash[k].map {|v| "#{k}:#{v}"}}.flatten.join(",")
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to call flatten before calling join. Join flattens automatically.